# In R, how can I sum a a column of data between a date and a date in the past and within another variable, similar to the sumifs function in excel

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, partition, sumifs

I am using the nycflightdata13 library as the example.

I want to calculate the total flying time of any given aircraft in the 10 days previous to the date of the flight described in the row

```
row tailnum flyingtime  dep_date
1   N14228  227 1/1/2013
2   N24211  227 1/1/2013
3   N619AA  160 1/1/2013
4   N24211  252 1/2/2013
5   N14228  150 1/8/2013
6   N24211  308 1/8/2013
7   N14228  39  1/9/2013
8   N14228  149 1/9/2013
9   N24211  319 1/9/2013
10  N24211  344 1/10/2013
11  N24211  360 1/11/2013
12  N14228  43  1/13/2013
13  N24211  145 1/13/2013
14  N24211  33  1/16/2013
```

In excel i would use something with the structure of  `=sumifs(flyingtime,dep_date,"<"&row.dep_date,dep_date,">="&row.dep_date-10,tailnum,row.tailnum)` and in SQL i would use some sort of partitioned sub query

to get the result of

```
tailnum flyingtime  dep_date    flying_10
N14228  227 1/1/2013    0.00
N24211  227 1/1/2013    0.00
N619AA  160 1/1/2013    0.00
N24211  252 1/2/2013    227.00
N14228  150 1/8/2013    227.00
N24211  308 1/8/2013    479.00
N14228  39  1/9/2013    377.00
N14228  149 1/9/2013    377.00
N24211  319 1/9/2013    787.00
N24211  344 1/10/2013   1106.00
N24211  360 1/11/2013   1450.00
N14228  43  1/13/2013   338.00
N24211  145 1/13/2013   1331.00
N24211  33  1/16/2013   1476.00
```

But I can't quite land on the right syntax to get this right in R

I have searched a lot and none of the solutions I have found match this issue and my R skills are not quite there to apply them to this. I am familiar with `dplyr` and `data.table`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In true SO form, i have found the answer within 1 hour of posting. here [Excel SUMIFS equivalent in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720897/excel-sumifs-equivalent-in-r) thanks to @akrun

```
fh <- as.data.table(fh)
fh$sumifs <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(fh)), function(i) with(fh, sum(air_time[tailnum == tailnum[i] & time_hour < time_hour[i] & time_hour >= time_hour[i]-10])))
```

Comment: This would be awfully slow and in inefficient for a big data set

Answer (score -1):

In `dplyr` you can sum with conditions [as seen in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528862/summarize-with-conditions-in-dplyr)

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(sum10 = sum(B[A<=10]))
```

Comment: I can see how that works when the comparator is a constant i.e. 10, but how can I apply it to each row when the value of dep_date is different?